# Data confirm should include name or value of checked radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, confirm

I will like to display dynamic content as part of a data confirm message when the user clinks on submit. In my views I have,

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="team" id="<%= team.id %>" value="<%= team.id %>">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="<%= team.id %>">
    <span id="form-check-team"><%= team.short_name %></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <%= form.submit 'Submit', :data => {:confirm => 'Confirm you have chosen?'} %>
</div>
```

I will like to have dynamic content in the dialoge box like so

```
<%= form.submit 'Submit', :data => {:confirm => 'Confirm you have chosen #{team.shortname}'} %>
```

So basically, if an input is checked, how do I get the text of the id #form-check-team

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use JS here, to concatenate text that you need to add.

Comment: How do I go about that. My JS skills is not top notch

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is when the checkbox's value changes, modify the value of `data-confirm` on the submit button:

```js
document.querySelector('.form-check-input').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var $submitButton = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
  var $teamNameElement = document.getElementById('form-check-team');
  var $checkBox = event.target;

  var originalMessage = null;
  if ($checkBox.checked) {
    // When the checkbox is checked, update the message to include the team name
    originalMessage = $submitButton.getAttribute('data-confirm');
    $submitButton.setAttribute('data-confirm-original', originalMessage);
    $submitButton.setAttribute('data-confirm', 'Confirm you have chosen ' + $teamNameElement.textContent + '?');
  } else {
    // When the checkbox is unchecked, restore the original message
    originalMessage = $submitButton.getAttribute('data-confirm-original');
    $submitButton.setAttribute('data-confirm', originalMessage);
    $submitButton.removeAttribute('data-confirm-original');
  }
});
```

But, if the contents of `#form-check-team` does not change from what it was rendered from the server, then it would be easier to just set the confirm message from the server itself:

```
<%= form.submit 'Submit', data: { confirm: "Confirm you have chosen #{team.shortname}" } %>
```